# VS2019 ver16.9.4 infinite loading after "publish"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to publish my first little program that I can open from my desktop (so an .exe file).
It is made with Visual studio 2019 and is written in VBnet (Windows Forms App).

When I set "debug" to "release" and right click my project in the Solution Explorer then the circle starts rotating infinite (30min+) without giving any pop-up or other information. The notice bar at the bottom is Blue and says "Ready".

My .vbproj looks like this:

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>LABEL_lastchanges</RootNamespace>
    <StartupObject>LABEL_lastchanges.Form1</StartupObject>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Import Include="LABEL_lastchanges" />
    <Import Include="System.Data" />
    <Import Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Import Include="System.Globalization" />
    <Import Include="System.IO" />
    <Import Include="System.Linq.Expressions" />
    <Import Include="System.Text" />
    <Import Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="My Project\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I hope I have given enough information for you to help me, thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't need to change debug to release. Publish publishes release versions. Restart VS and move on with your life?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio
I followed this, and in here it states that you should?
Also I already restarted VS without result. I'm doing this as a request to get to know visual basic in a company setting, so just moving on is not an option.

Comment: To address a commenter, start your comment with an @ followed by the name of the person you wish to address. Note it is usually provided in a pop up when you begin to type.

Comment: @KevinVR: You stated: "I'm doing this as a request to get to know visual basic in a company setting". Are you on an internship? If so, you may consider asking your colleagues (mentors) for assistance.

Comment: @user9938 No, I'm not an intern but I am fairly new so they are trying to get me to meet every type of programming software they use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial that you mentioned, [Tutorial: Publish a .NET console application using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/publishing-with-visual-studio), mentions a prerequisite of [Tutorial: Create a .NET console application using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio) which creates a Console Application. However, based on additional information that you provided, it seems that you are creating a Windows Forms project instead. The information below assumes that you're creating a Windows Forms App (using .NET 5).

**Ensure your using Visual Studio 16.9.4 (or greater) and required workloads are installed**

- Open **Visual Studio Installer**
- If necessary, update Visual Studio version, by clicking "Update".
- Click **Modify**
  [image]
- Click **Workloads** tab
- Ensure the following Workloads are installed (checked). If a workload isn't checked, check it, to select it for installation.

  [image]

  [image]

**Note**: It's okay to install additional workloads.

**Individual Components**

- Ensure **.NET 5.0 Runtime** is checked. If not, check it.
- Ensure **.NET SDK** is checked. If not, check it.
- Ensure **ClickOnce Publishing** is checked. If not, check it.
- Ensure **NuGet package manager** is checked. If not, check it.

**Note**: It's okay to install additional individual components.

If you checked any workloads or individual components, in lower-right corner, select **Download all, then install**, then click **Modify**

[image]

Ensure that your development environment is properly setup.

- Open **Visual Studio 2019**
- In lower-right corner click **Continue without code**

  [image]
- On VS menu, click **Tools**
- Select **Options**
- Expand **NuGet Package Manager**
- Under "Package Management", ensure that "Default package management format" is set to **PackageReference**. If you made any changes, click "OK".

[image]

For more information, see [Package references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files).

**Create new project**

- In VS menu, click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- Select **Visual Basic  Windows  Desktop**

  [image]
- Click **Windows Forms App**
  [image]
- Click **Next**
- Enter desired project name and select desired location
- Click **Next**
- For "Target Framework", select **.NET 5.0 (Current)**
  [image]
- Click **Create**
- In VS menu, click **File**
- Select **Save All**
- In VS menu, click **Build**
- Select **Configuration Manager**
- For "Active solution configuration", select **Release**. Click **Close**
- In VS menu, click **Build**
- Select **Build Solution**
- In VS menu, click **Build**
- Select **Publish** <project name>
- Select the desired option (ex: ClickOnce)
  [image]
- Click **Next**.

**Note**:  Depending on the option that you've selected, additional dialogs may appear. Select desired options and click the appropriate button (at bottom) to complete the process.

**Additional Resources**:

- [Install .NET on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/windows?tabs=net50#install-with-visual-studio)

Comment: I will follow this guide when I have acces to my work computer, thank you for the response

Comment: Also see https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem for how to report issues with VS.